# How to Retrive Apple App Store Rating Details

Tags: ios, app-store

I have an iOS Application and whenever a user rates the application in the app store then i need to get the rating details.

For Eg; If a user gives 4 star ratings then i need to get that value.I need that value for some functionalities in my application.

Is there any API to get these values.....?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find out programmatically who has given 5 star rating to our iPhone app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8164965/find-out-programmatically-who-has-given-5-star-rating-to-our-iphone-app)

Answer (score 5):

There is a way you can find the customer Reviews with rating of the application.The API url is below.

https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/customerreviews/id=284882215/sortBy=mostRecent/json

You need to specify your AppId instead of 284882215.

Answer (score 2):

Nope. There is no way for you to find out what was the rating that the user gives at AppStore.